# dotnet compact framework 3.5 sp1 detect device resolution

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I need to detect the device resolution automatically, right now I have a global var & hardwire the resolution:

```
Public gDeviceRes As String = "640"
'Public gDeviceRes As String = "320"
```

then recompile for each device, does anyone have a quick snippit of code for this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your exact needs, you can check the current screen dimensions with [Screen.PrimaryScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen.aspx) or you can P/Invoke [GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms929469.aspx) with SM_CXSCREEN or [GetDeviceCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms929295.aspx) with HORZRES. Vertical dimesions are similarly available.

Answer (score 3):

This did exactly what i needed:

```
  Dim screensize As System.Drawing.Rectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
  Public gDeviceRes As String = screensize.Height
```